# bloginfo('template_directory') in jQuery to be used in Admin Panel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to customize contact form 7 database and for it I need to use bloginfo('template_directory') in jQuery.

As suggested in earlier posts I tried :

1. I tried adding variable in header.php
2. Used `wp_localize_script` & `enqueue_script`
3. Even tried `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);`

But no luck. Please advise.

My Mistake as I didn't posted codes. Here are the codes that I am trying to use in wp admin where I am getting error for **var custom.templateDir**  :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    jQuery(".acceptEntry").on("click", function($)        
    {
        $.preventDefault();

        console.log(custom.templateDir);

        var name_1 = jQuery('.name span').text();
        console.log(name_1);

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: custom.templateDir  + "/php-new-page.php",
          data: { name: name_1 }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });    
    });
});
```

For **templateDir**, I even tried :

1. url: "/php-new-page.php"
2. Defining **var templateDir** in header.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2):

**bloginfo** function **echoed** the output, you need a return function like

> **get_bloginfo();**

Suggest to use  get_template_directory_uri() instead of get_bloginfo().

Answer (score 0):

```
   function my_js_variables(){ ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxURL = '<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>';
            var ajaxnonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "itr_ajax_nonce" ); ?>';
          </script>
          <?php }
    add_action ( 'wp_head', 'my_js_variables' );
```

gives me me html codes on header.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ajaxURL = 'http://www.eweb.co/mcb/wp/wp-content/themes/mcb';
</script>
```

But how to access **ajaxURL** on admin side?